# Whenever I execute function getting error Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I wrote below function using T-SQL, but whenever I execute it, I get an error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[get_lapsed_days]
(
    @month INT,
    @year INT,
    @siteid INT
)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE @lapsed_days AS INT;
    SELECT @lapsed_days = (
        SELECT CASE
                WHEN eil.RULE_TYPE = 'Remuneration'
                    THEN (
                        SELECT (SUM(etts.GENERAL_SHIFT + etts.FIRST_SHIFT + etts.SECOND_SHIFT + etts.THIRD_SHIFT))
                        FROM dbo.EMP_FPONM_EMP_TIME_SHEET etts
                        WHERE etts.emp_id = eil.emp_code
                            AND etts.month = @month
                            AND etts.year = @year
                            AND etts.SITE_ID = @siteid
                    )
                WHEN eil.RULE_TYPE = 'Comp-Off'
                    THEN (
                        SELECT (LAPSED_DAYS) * 8
                        FROM EMP_FPONM_COMP_OFF_BALANCE
                        WHERE EMP_FPONM_COMP_OFF_BALANCE.EMP_ID = eil.EMP_CODE
                            AND EMP_FPONM_COMP_OFF_BALANCE.month = @month
                            AND EMP_FPONM_COMP_OFF_BALANCE.year = @year
                            AND EMP_FPONM_COMP_OFF_BALANCE.SITE_ID = @siteid
                    )
                ELSE 0
            END
        FROM dbo.EMP_FPONM_EMPLOYEE_INFORMATION eil
    )
    RETURN @lapsed_days

END
```

Comment: Problem lies in Case Condition it is giving more than one value that's what error is saying and Local variable will not take more than 1 value

Comment: ok Thanks u how solve this

Comment: we need to filter condition then SELECT TOP 1 before CASE WHEN

Comment: why you have used dbo.EMP_FPONM_EMP_TIME_SHEET table two times you can just use the same table once

Comment: If iam using select top 1 before case when its getting only top one value

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[get_lapsed_days]
(
    @month INT,
    @year INT,
    @siteid INT
)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN

    RETURN (
        SELECT SUM(
                CASE
                    WHEN eil.RULE_TYPE = 'Remuneration'
                        THEN ETS.GENERAL_SHIFT + ETS.FIRST_SHIFT + ETS.SECOND_SHIFT + ETS.THIRD_SHIFT
                    ELSE 0
                END)
            FROM dbo.EMP_FPONM_EMPLOYEE_INFORMATION eil
            JOIN dbo.EMP_FPONM_EMP_TIME_SHEET ETS ON eil.emp_code = ETS.emp_id
            WHERE ETS.site_id = @siteid
                AND ETS.month = @month
                AND ETS.year = @year
    )

END
```

Update:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[get_lapsed_days]
(
    @month INT,
    @year INT,
    @siteid INT
)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE @lapsed_days INT
    SELECT @lapsed_days = (
        SELECT SUM(
            CASE
                WHEN eil.RULE_TYPE = 'Remuneration' THEN etts.GENERAL_SHIFT + etts.FIRST_SHIFT + etts.SECOND_SHIFT + etts.THIRD_SHIFT
                WHEN eil.RULE_TYPE = 'Comp-Off' THEN LAPSED_DAYS * 8
            END
        )
        FROM dbo.EMP_FPONM_EMPLOYEE_INFORMATION eil
        LEFT JOIN dbo.EMP_FPONM_COMP_OFF_BALANCE b ON b.EMP_ID = eil.EMP_CODE
            AND b.[month] = @month
            AND b.[year] = @year
            AND b.SITE_ID = @siteid
            AND eil.RULE_TYPE = 'Comp-Off'
        LEFT JOIN dbo.EMP_FPONM_EMP_TIME_SHEET etts ON etts.emp_id = eil.emp_code
            AND etts.month = @month
            AND etts.year = @year
            AND etts.SITE_ID = @siteid
            AND eil.RULE_TYPE = 'Remuneration'
        WHERE eil.RULE_TYPE IN ('Comp-Off', 'Remuneration')
    )
    RETURN ISNULL(@lapsed_days, 0)

END
```

Comment: @sahithi you are welcome ;) also check this post about `ELSE 0`: http://blog.devart.com/what-is-faster-inside-stream-aggregate-hash-match.html

Comment: I HAVE ONE MORE ISSUE HERE ONLY WHEN REMENERATION WE ARE CALCULTAED BUT I NEED ONE WHEN CONDITION HOW TO USE

Comment: @sahithi: *"I have one more issue..."* Questions cannot be moving targets. If Devart's answer answered your original question, accept the answer. If you have a *different* question, post it, being clear about how it's different. Also, PLEASE DON'T SHOUT.

Comment: I POSTED ORIGINAL QUESTION SO PLEASE HELP ME THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: Thank u very much its working fine but i have doubt why sum add before case start

Comment: This is a `T-SQL` syntax. Please check book: http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Server-Fundamentals-Developer-Reference/dp/0735658145